# I can't click modals buttons with Nightwatch

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I can't find anywhere how to click a modal button. The hard part is that all the modals buttons in this website have the same id so when i try the simple click() command it only works for the very first modal of the website.

EDIT

Actually my bad. I can't click modal's buttons.

EDIT 2

I have two pages with the same modal appearing in both. My problem is when i try to hit those buttons in my second page. It seems like it reacts only to fist modal.

```
<body class="bg ng-scope" ng-app="app">
<div class="ng-scope" autoscroll="true" ui-view="" style="">
<div class="ng-scope" src="'/js/layout/navbar.html'" ng-include="" style="">
<div id="searchContainer" class="container ng-scope">
<div id="resultsContainer" class="container ng-scope ng-hide" ng-show="vm.isAvailable"> </div>
<div class="ng-scope" src="'/js/layout/modals.html'" ng-include="" style="">
<script id="myModalContent.html" class="ng-scope" type="text/ng-template">
<div class="modal fade children-policy-modal ng-scope">
<div class="modal fade articles-modal ng-scope">
<div class="modal fade booking-code-modal ng-scope" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<form class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" role="form" name="vm.bookingCodeForm">
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm ng-binding" ng-click="vm.checkBookingCode()" type="submit">BUTTON 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default ng-binding" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">BUTTON2</button>
```

EDIT 3 
I used the following code

```
.click('a[data-target=".voucher-code-modal"]')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[class="btn btn-default ng-binding"]', 5000)
      .click('button[class="btn btn-default ng-binding"]')
```

and i get the following message

> Warn: waitForElement found 9 elements for selector button[class="btn
>   btn-default ng-binding"]'}. Only the first one will be checked.

And then i get timed out cause of time.

Comment: whenever a modal appears or disappears..there is an attribute to its HTML tag or to its parent tag which changes for e.g: style attribute changing to display:block / none" you need to locate which attribute changes

Comment: Actually the style attribute changes. But how can this help me?

Answer (score 0):

So your xpath should be something like this: `.//div[@id='your id' and contains(@style,'display: block')]` this will give only those modals..which appear on clicking..also ensure the result count with above xpath should be 1..Please note above xpath is not tried and tested, but something on those lines should give your answer.

Comment: should my Xpath be absolute? Can i do this with css selector?

Comment: XPath always have to be relative and yes you should be able to do this with css as well.. it would be worth if you can add HTML to the post so that we can suggest relevant locator

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to select a text area inside a modal window

```
'md-dialog[aria-label="Url Document ..."] textarea[name="description"]'
```

That makes my setvalue code look like

```
.setValue('md-dialog[aria-label="Url Document ..."] textarea[name="description"]', 'random string')
```

Not the nicest line of code, but Page Objects lets you tidy it up.

From what I can work out in your code snippet you'd want something like

```
.click(form[name='vm.bookingCodeForm'] button[type='submit'])
```

Comment: nop i am getting the same error like my code. I edited the post.